# How to forward param to JSP based on condition

Tags: html, jsp, post, http-post

I have a jsp page with multiple submit buttons. Now, if I want to forward params to a jsp file based on which submit button the user clicked i.e. based on some condition. How this can be done?

I am thinking to use jsp:forward to pass jsp:params (defined in the caller page). But, I am not being able to figure out how to make the param name conditional.

Can anybody suggest how this can be implemented?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Somnath

Comment: "*I am thinking to use `jsp:forward` to pass `jsp:params`*" means are you dealing with JSTL/EL?

Comment: yes I have added JSTL 1.2 and standard jars in the build path. But I am not using JSTL for tag prefixes like <c:import>. For JSP tags like <jsp:forward> or <jsp:params> tags, I think the JSTL is not necessary. What do you think?

Comment: JSTL is not needed for this kind of tasks (but beware that you must use the minimum scriptlet).In JSP,you can simply use `request.getRequestDispatcher()` or `request.sendRedirect()` methods of the request object to redirect to a specific page (Google for the difference between them) and you can conditionally check which button is clicked by simply applying the if condition something like this `if(request.getParameter("ButtonName")!=null){ //redirect to another page using request.getRequestDispatcher() or request.sendRedirect()}` irrespective of how many buttons you have on the same form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using a servlet how about something like this? This is with `JSTL`.

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${param.button1}">
<jsp: forward page="page1.jsp">
  <jsp: param name="myParam" value="whatever1"/>
</jsp: forward>
</c:when>
<c:when test="${param.button2}">
<jsp: forward page="page2.jsp">
  <jsp: param name="myParam" value="whatever2"/>
</jsp: forward>
</c:when>
</c:choose>

<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="submit" name="button1" value="button1" />
<input type="submit" name="button2" value="button2" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give each submit button a different value. See
http://www.chami.com/tips/internet/042599I.html

Answer (score 0):

What about have each submit button be a button in the form and then when it is clicked call a javascript function that determines where it came from, or have the function be unique and then forward that value to the servlet as a parmeter.